# React Native Android: allow to invoke callback multiple times

Tags: java, android, react-native

I would like to know how to allow a callback to be invoked multiple times in React Native Android app.

My Android native module saves callback using `com.facebook.react.bridge.Callback` and periodically calls it using `AlarmManager.setRepeating`.

The code sort of looks like this.

```
public class BackgroundAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static Callback callback;

    private void executeCallback() {
        Log.d("BackgroundAlarmReceiver", "Performing background work...");
        try {
            callback.invoke();
        } catch (IllegalViewOperationException e) {
            Log.d("BackgroundAlarmReceiver", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

But callback is only allowed to be run once (see [the code from React Native repo](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/bridge/CallbackImpl.java#L31-L35)). How can I save the reference to the callback provided by my JavaScript code, and keep calling it periodically?

Answer (score 2):

Use RCTDeviceEventEmitter instead of callbacks.

Subscribe in JS:

```
DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('onError',(error) => console.log(error))
```

Send events from native code:

```
this.getReactApplicationContext().getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class).emit(name,data);
```

`This` refers to a `ReactContextBaseJavaModule` instance.
Working fine on react 0.53